# How do I open a website on an iPhone using java card on an NFC-B card?

Tags: nfc, javacard, ndef

I am trying to use an OMNI from [NFCRing](https://store.nfcring.com/products/omni?variant=30878229987373) to send a website to Apple and Android phones. I'm new to NFC so I don't really know what I'm doing.

So far I have attempted to build and install the full NDEF applet from [OpenJavacardNDEF](https://github.com/OpenJavaCard/openjavacard-ndef) using version 20.01.23 of the [GlobalPlatformPro API](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro). Whenever I try to send ADPU commands to the card, however, the response is always 0x6D00.

Edit:

The APDU commands I have tried are 00000000, 00a4000c, 00a4000c02e10400, and 00b00150 all with the same response. I am trying to follow the protocol outlined in the [applet's documentation](https://github.com/OpenJavaCard/openjavacard-ndef/blob/master/doc/protocol.md) but I may be doing something wrong; as I said I am new to this.

Comment: You need to elaborate on "send ADPU commands", what APDU commands and how are you sending them.

Comment: I have updated the post with the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not doing the first step of actually selecting your Application, that protocol doc you linked only give you the details of how it can respond to each type of command once selected.

As you are trying to emulate a NFC Type 4 Tag I would read the NFC [specification doc](http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-4-Tag_2.0.pdf)  Section 5.4 is the most relevant.

But as a shortcut:-

The first ADPU to send is  `00h A4h 04h 00h 07h D2760000850101h 00h`

This is select the NFC Ndef App standard AID number (the D276... part)

If you look at the OpenJavaCardNDEF example client library on [connect](https://github.com/OpenJavaCard/openjavacard-ndef/blob/c036bab36a9ea85f01dcb812405ee870d0da20aa/client/src/main/java/org/openjavacard/ndef/client/NdefClient.java#L72) and [performSelectApplet](https://github.com/OpenJavaCard/openjavacard-ndef/blob/c036bab36a9ea85f01dcb812405ee870d0da20aa/client/src/main/java/org/openjavacard/ndef/client/NdefClient.java#L153) do just this.

Further APDU's are needed once the applet is selected, I would read the NDEF spec and or the example client library on which ones are needed to do what you want from the Tag.